# Como hacer en reactJS envento que muestre el calendario dando click a un icono

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

estoy tratando de hacer un evento en react para que cuando le de click al icono del calendario me lo muestre pero no he podido
[image: t]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div className="form-group">
  <span>prueba:</span>
  <label htmlFor="hasta" className="until-label">
                                        <input type="date" name="hasta" id="hasta" min={this.state.startDate} max={this.formatoFecha(new Date, 0)} value={this.state.endDate}
                                               onChange={e => this.handleChangeEndDate(e)} className="form-control search-inputdate aling-self-date"/>
                                        <span className="filter-icon icon-calendar-01">
                                        <span className="path1"></span><span className="path2"></span><span className="path3"></span><span className="path4"></span><span className="path5"></span>
                                        <span className="path6"></span><span className="path7"></span><span className="path8"></span><span className="path9"></span><span className="path10"></span>
                                        <span className="path11"></span><span className="path12"></span><span className="path13"></span><span className="path14"></span><span className="path15"></span>
                                        <span className="path16"></span><span className="path17"></span><span className="path18"></span><span className="path19"></span><span className="path20"></span>
                                        </span>
                                     </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Estas usando clases, hooks, refs? Comparte el código del componente así tenemos una mejor idea de lo que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Si mal lo recuerdo hay un modulo llamado react-datepicker, investigarlo porque es el resultado que buscas...

Para instalarlo era: `npm i react-datepicker`

acá encontre el modulo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker